# Converting a DFA to a regular expression

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

[image]

I have this state diagram, and I am trying to describe the language of this DFA and finding the regular expression for it.

I tried doing it by listing possible strings and at first I thought it was strings that have odd numbers of 1 or 0 in the end but it is not the case. I've been trying to figure out for the last 30 minutes and need help. How would you describe the language for this state diagram as well as the regular expression for it? Thank you!

Comment: There are several general solutions [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions). In my opinion it is a very technical question.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. It accepts strings with an odd number of ones AND an odd number of zeroes.